# Getting Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401 on api call java Script

Tags: javascript

Actually when i am hitting api with basic auth username password  in Postman , Browser its giving me response 
but when i am running api from code its giving me error Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

this my code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
 if (this.readyState === 4) {
console.log(this.responseText);
}
});

xhr.open("GET", "http://35.154.114.184:8080/api/category");
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic YWRtaW5AbWVsbG9lLmluOm9yaWxlbMw==");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Seems CORS comes into action there. Are you running this script from the same domain (`http://35.154.114.184:8080`) ?

Comment: no its not on same domain

Comment: Does cross origin requests are allowed in your server?

Comment: I think not but server side code is developing by some one